# Inserting data at specific position in XML

Tags: c#, xml, string

I want to read an XML file and match tag `</contrib-group>` and write a string after this tag

```
string Final = File.ReadAllText(Npath);
string Oxml = path + "\\" + Oword + ".abs.xml";
if (File.Exists(Oxml))
{
    StreamReader xml = new StreamReader(Oxml,Encoding.UTF8);
    string xmltag = xml.ReadToEnd();
    //File.OpenWrite(Oxml);
    xml.Close();
    StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(Oxml, true, Encoding.UTF8);
    Match tag = Regex.Match(xmltag, @"</contrib-group>");
    if (tag.Success == true)
    {
        write.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
        write.Write(Final);

    }
}
```

So I need to write the string `Final` to the XML file called `Oxml` after the matched XML tag `</contrib-group>`

Comment: Stop. Back away from the computer. There are classes available in .NET framework for dealing with [XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml(v=vs.110).aspx). Regex is not one of those classes.

Comment: So what is your question exactly? What is your code doing right now that is not correct?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever am new to C# Society, so if you can help me i will be grateful

Comment: i know @JohnWillemse i wanna to know how to do that how to write after tag in xml specially this tag

Comment: What is the text in `NPath`? Is it just meant to be plain text, or more XML? Also note that your variable names are unconventional and not really meaningful.

Comment: @JonSkeet i know i will edit all this names later but now i wanna to fix the functionality of the main program. Also about the text in `NPath` is some xml tags and text in i wanna to tell you that i matched the tag successfully but can not write directly after the tag

Comment: @MohamedSayed: So you're trying to merge XML documents? Basically, you should abandon the approach of treating these as text, and instead treat them as XML documents. It would be helpful if you could give us samples of the XML involved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to save the new content as a valid XML file which you can work with, you should use the XML classes for that approach, this should look like this (untested):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("YourFile.xml");
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList elemList = root.GetElementsByTagName("contrib-group");
for (int i=0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{       
    XmlNode xnode = elemList[i];
    XmlNode xnodeParent = xnode.ParentNode;
    XMLNode newNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "NodeName", "");
    newNode.InnerText = "ContentInsideTheNode";
    xnodeParent.InsertAfter(newNode, xnode);
}
doc.Save("YourFile.xml");
```

If you only need to replace the string for other purposes than saving it where having a valid XML is not an issue you can just handle it as a string and use the [String.Replace (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) Method

```
string searchedTag = @"</contrib-group>";    
string tagAndNewContent = @"</contrib-group>" + newContent;
string fileContentString = File.ReadAllText("YourFile.xml");    
string ouput = fileContentString.Replace(searchedTag, tagAndNewContent);
```